# changing the volume API via AppleScript is rounded down in Spotify

Tags: applescript, spotify

**Steps to reproduce**

calling:

```
tell application "Spotify"
if it is running then
    set sound volume to (sound volume * .10)
end if
end tell
```

then:

```
tell application "Spotify"
if it is running then
    set sound volume to (sound volume * 10)
end if
end tell
```

**Observed behavior**

Calling repeatedly lowers the volume of the app.

**Expected behavior**

App should go back to the original volume (as rdio and iTunes do)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the volume is not decrease to 0,

```
set sound volume to (sound volume * 10)
```

will increase the volume again.  Once it reaches 0, 0x10 = 0